# Function does not push to the empty array to create list. How to fix this

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to add items to the hobbies list via function call. But it's not added and i have been getting empty array all the time. There is something silly I am missing. Can you some please guide me to resolve this. I am including all code I am working on.

I have tried calling the function like.
person().addHobby('TestHobby');

```
function person(firstName, lastName) {

    var FullName = firstName + ' ' + lastName;
    var hobbies = [‘’];

    return {

        /**
         * Returns truthy if the person already has this hobby
         * @param {string} hobby
         * @returns {boolean}
         */
        hasHobby: function(hobby) {
            return hobbies.indexOf(hobby)>=0;
        },

        /**
         * Returns the person's hobbies after adding the given hobby
         * @param {string} hobby
         * @returns {array}
         */
        addHobby: function(hobby) {
            return hobbies.indexOf(hobby)>0 ? hobbies : hobbies.push(hobby);
        },

        /**
         * Returns the person's hobbies after removing the given hobby
         * @param {string} hobby
         * @returns {array}
         */
        removeHobby: function(hobby) {
            if (hobbies.indexOf(hobby)>0) {
                // note: filter is a standard array function that creates a new array
                // with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function
                hobbies = hobbies.filter(function(hobby) { 
                    return hobby != hobby;
                });
                return hobbies;
            } else {
                return hobbies;
            }
        },

        /**
         * Returns the person's hobbies
         * @returns {array}
         */
        getHobbies: function() {
            return hobbies
        },

        /**
         * Returns the person's full name
         * @returns {string}
         */
        getName: function() {
            return FullName;
        },

  };
};
```

Comment: `‘’` are not valid quotes. This is probably causing an error. Also `push()` returns the length of the array after the item is added.

Comment: Note that `array.push` doesn't return the array itself, so your addHobby is lying about its return type. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you aren't sure what you've actually created here.
This is a class definition for person. To call it's methods you need to create a new instance of person like:

```
var gregory=new person();
```

gregory is your reference to your freshly created person. To give gregory a hobby:

```
gregory.addHobby("sleeping");
```

Now you can query his hobbies like:

```
console.log(gregory.getHobbies());
```

Comment: It's not necessary the use of the `new` keyword, since `person()` is a factory function. You can simply create persons without `new` :  `var gregory = person()`

Comment: Ah, I see. I wasn't aware of those factory functions in ES6.

Comment: @obscure factory functions are just functions, they have existed forever. You just have a function that returns an anonymous object. Note that calling `new` on a function that returns an object is the same thing as just calling it with `()` because the prototype chain is not attached

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your person and then use it. Like this:

```
var p = new person();
p.addHobby("test");
console.log(p.getHobbies());
```

```js
function person(firstName, lastName) {

    var FullName = firstName + ' ' + lastName;
    var hobbies = [];

    return {

        /**
         * Returns truthy if the person already has this hobby
         * @param {string} hobby
         * @returns {boolean}
         */
        hasHobby: function(hobby) {
            return hobbies.indexOf(hobby)>=0;
        },

        /**
         * Returns the person's hobbies after adding the given hobby
         * @param {string} hobby
         * @returns {array}
         */
        addHobby: function(hobby) {
            return hobbies.indexOf(hobby)>0 ? hobbies : hobbies.push(hobby);
        },

        /**
         * Returns the person's hobbies after removing the given hobby
         * @param {string} hobby
         * @returns {array}
         */
        removeHobby: function(hobby) {
            if (hobbies.indexOf(hobby)>0) {
                // note: filter is a standard array function that creates a new array
                // with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function
                hobbies = hobbies.filter(function(hobby) { 
                    return hobby != hobby;
                });
                return hobbies;
            } else {
                return hobbies;
            }
        },

        /**
         * Returns the person's hobbies
         * @returns {array}
         */
        getHobbies: function() {
            return hobbies
        },

        /**
         * Returns the person's full name
         * @returns {string}
         */
        getName: function() {
            return FullName;
        },

  };
};

var p = new person();
p.addHobby("test");
console.log(p.getHobbies());
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `addHobbies` function you're returning the result of `push()` wich is the new length of the array and not the actual array.

Try this:

```
addHobby: function(hobby) {
   if (hobbies.indexOf(hobby) < 0) {
      hobbies.push(hobby)
   }

   return hobbies;
}
```

Also you have to create a person if you want to get its hobbies array updated later:

```
var fred = person();
console.log(fred.addHobby("Test hobbie"));
console.log(fred.getHobbies())
```